# What would be best layout for registration form containing 14 input fields.

Tags: forms, html

I made a form for this but user have to scroll through which seems like not too easy [image]

So it still bit long

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/27840/what-fields-to-drop-from-the-registration-form?rq=1
- Might be of some help

Answer (score 6):

Like Nick and Carlos stated, best would be to shorten the form and include only what is absolutely necessary.

However, **another option** would be to group these questions into sections and break them down into steps. Breaking up the form and showing the user their progress helps make the form less intimidating.

Here's an example of what that may look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Try and shorten the registration form.**

What are essentials? Only ask for that and have them fill out the less important items later when they are already registered.

If it is not possible to do this because of how your app works or the goals you have, you can make the form look shorter by having clear steps in your flow. An example could be a step about the company name/website and the second step about contact information.

Also remove the in-field help label. It makes your form look crowded and 'Enter country' doesn't add much compared to the 'Country' label above.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Nick in terms of only having the fields that are absolutely necessary so that you do what you want to do. I also agree that by grouping information will make the form easier to 'digest' and therefore, easier to fill in.

You have some fundamental issues on your inputs:

- Year founded should be a numeric input and not a select option. If
  you have a option selection between 1900 and 2017 that means the user
  will have to scroll through 117 options. That's impractical;
- Support page URL, Contact page URL, Country don't make sense in terms of grouping, what is the user filling in?
- Is active, what does this mean?

The best thing you can do is, understand what fields you need to have there so you can do what you're trying to do. You can do this by talking with your users and have them tell you what are they willing to give at that stage of the journey.

Once you have these then you come up with a form that makes sense in terms of information grouping. Depending on the information you require you need to group these fields.

And finally, test it with users, see what they say and readjust based on the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Have categories in the form. Group related information &
Form looks better when it's categorized.

**Grouping related fields together also help users make sense of the information that they must fill in.**

[image]